# Filtering, replacing and reappending a column to base df in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Imagine the following dataframe

Base dataframe

```
df  = pd.from_dict({'a': [1,2,1,2,1]
 'b': [1,1,3,3,1]
})
```

And them i pick up the a, column and replace a few values based on b column values

```
df.loc[df['b']== 3]['a'].replace(2,1)
```

How could i reappend my a column to my original df, but only changing those specific filtered values?

Wanted result

```
df  = pd.from_dict({'a': [1,2,1,1,1]
     'b': [1,1,3,3,1]
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do with `update`

```
df.update(df.loc[df['b']== 3,['a']].replace(2,1))
df
Out[354]: 
     a  b
0  1.0  1
1  2.0  1
2  1.0  3
3  1.0  3
4  1.0  1
```

Comment: Ah this method is gonna be so usefull thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try `df.mask`

```py
df['a'] = df['a'].mask(df['a'].eq(2) & df['b'].eq(3), 1)
```

```
print(df)

   a  b
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  1  3
3  1  3
4  1  1
```

Comment: Question i noticed that you use, that eq() as your comparison operator is there any reason on why? I am wondering if i should start using them too instead of ==. Or you just use it for cleaner code?

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 Use `eq` can get rid of the parenthesis when concatting multiple condition.